# How to compress this mysqldump?

Tags: shell-scripting

i have this script and it works but the output isn't zipped so it's huge. I want to save it zipped but i don't understand shell script and i don't want to mess it up. Can you help me zip it like so: ".sql.zip", please?

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $mysql_host -u $mysql_username -p$mysql_password $mysql_database > $backup_path/$today/$mysql_database-`date +%H%M`.sql
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you can just do this.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $mysql_host -u $mysql_username -p$mysql_password $mysql_database | gzip -9 -c > $backup_path/$today/$mysql_database-`date +%H%M`.sql.gz
```

Comment: I found `gzip -9` very slow. I'm using default compression level, which produces about 10% bigger files and takes 50% of time in my case (20GB+ database).

Answer (score 7):

Just 'pipe the output' to `gzip`

The command would become this:

```
 /usr/bin/mysqldump -h $mysql_host -u $mysql_username -p$mysql_password $mysql_database | gzip > $backup_path/$today/$mysql_database-`date +%H%M`.sql.gz
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe it though **gzip** (or **bzip2**, **pbzip2**, **xz**, etc...) like so:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $mysql_host -u $mysql_username -p$mysql_password $mysql_database | gzip -c > $backup_path/$today/$mysql_database-`date +%H%M`.sql.gz
```

**zip** isn't the optimal tool for this job because it stores data as files in an archive (like tar + gzip), where the other tools just compress data.

mysqldump (`mysqldump -C`) also supports compressed communication which could perhaps make things transfer faster over the network.

Comment: Funny all the same answers. I honestly posted at the same time as @Bert, but he was first.

Comment: What is the best answer of the 3 posted?
[gzip] - 
[gzip -c] - 
[gzip -9 -c]

Comment: @MichaelRogers `gzip` and `gzip -c` are the same. gzip -9 will be slower and cause heavier CPU usage (-6 is default) but would result in a higher compression ratio. I suggested alternative compression utilities, particularly `pbzip2` (a threaded bzip2) because compressing a large stream can consume 100% of one CPU core and could become a bottleneck. gzip is the most common (standard?) compression utility for Linux which is likely why everyone recommended it, but it's not the fastest or *best*. Some new algorithms such as xz and lz4 (a few more too) aim to be faster.