# How to compress SQL file correctly on CentOS?

Tags: centos, gzip, mysqldump

I have a database whose size is roughly 3.1 Gb according to PhpMyAdmin. 
I would like to dump and compress it with gzip.

This is a very similar answer to what I'm trying to do:
https://serverfault.com/a/804273/326635

Here is my command:

```
mysqldump -u myuser -p mydb | gzip -9 -c > db.gz
```

It works, I got the gz file. But it is over 3 Gb so the compression doesn't seem to be working. What do I wrong, how can I get a smaller file with gzip?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size of your mysqldump file is not going to be the same as your database size as reported by PHPMyAdmin.

First, create the dump file with the command:

```
mysqldump -u myuser -p mydb > dumpfile.sql
```

Record how large the file is. Then, compress the dump file with the command:

```
gzip -9 dumpfile.sql
```

Then compare the size of that new file.

Comment: Size of the SQL file in bytes is: 3,600,943,947

Size of the Gzip file in bytes is:   324,598,653
Ok, this seems solved the problem. Maybe I wrongly counted the bytes?